# Appending Decimal before writing an array of floats into excel with dataframes in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am reading some data from Postgresql to pandas dataframe. And some columns having array of float values. So, while writing dataframe to excel it is putting Decimal (as shown in figure) before the value.

[image]

Above image is what I am getting now. Below is what is expected.

[image]

Comment: can you post dataframe sample as a text?

Comment: No actually that would be confidential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['cellvoltages'] = df['cellvoltages'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

I have used above and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension with convert values to floats:

```
df['cellvoltages'] = df['cellvoltages'].apply(lambda x: [float(y) for y in x])
```